# Generate Scratch org definition settings for MDAPI settings

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, org-shape

I am trying to convert a messy orgs metadata into a DX project with a scratch org. Converting the metadata was easy using `sfdx:mdapi:convert` but pushing fails as the org shape doesn't match the `OrgSetting` files in the `settings` folder.

**Is there an y automated way to convert that into scratch org config settings or any other trick besides manual trial and error?**

Comment: Would using the [beta org shape for scratch orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_create_shape.htm) help you? You can create the "shape" details from an existing org.

Comment: @PhilW That could have been an answer, you know.

Comment: @sfdcfox, yes though only if I then added all the detail like you just did :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Org Shape for this purpose. First, [Enable Org Shape](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_enable_org_shape.htm) in the org you want to use as the source, set up the [Permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_permissions.htm) you need, then [Create an Org Shape](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_create_shape.htm). Finally, specify the [sourceOrg attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_scratch_def.htm) in your Scratch Org Definition File.

## Step 1: Enable Org Shape

As an admin, go to Setup > Org Shape > Enable. If your Dev Hub is different than the org you enable this in, enter the Org Id in the box.

## Step 2: Permissions

Create Permission Sets with the following permissions:

```
To Manage Scratch Orgs    Object Settings > Shape Representation > Create, Delete
To Use Org Shapes         Object Settings > Shape Representation > Read, View All
```

Assign them to developers that need to create/delete/use Org Shapes, as appropriate.

## Step 3: Create an Org Shape

```
sfdx force:org:shape:create -u <source org username/alias>
```

This creates the shape that you'll use in your Scratch Org Definition File.

## Step 4: Use the Org Shape

```
In the configuration file, specify the org you want to use:

{
  "orgName": "Acme",
  "sourceOrg": "00DB1230400Ifx5"
}
```